# Init vector used by AES algorithm in .NET forms authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, cryptography, forms-authentication, aes

What is the init vector used for the AES algorithm in .NET Forms Authentication? I see only a decryption key specified in the web.config file. I'm having to decrypt the cookies generated by .NET forms authentication in node js and I'm using node crypto's AES algorithm but want to know the init vector that .NET uses for it.

Answer (score 0):

The initialization vector (IV) is a random block of data, which should be different every time data is encrypted. Since the same IV used for encryption must be used for decryption, it is generally transmitted alongside the encrypted data. As the IV itself does not need to be protected it is often simply prepended to the encrypted data (as I believe is the case for .NET Forms Authentication cookies).

You should therefore be able to determine the IV by taking the first block-size bytes from the data, and using that as the IV in decrypting the remaining ciphertext.